# How to set up web service to download a file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web

I have a couple of third party web sites that need to allow files located on my servers to be downloaded by the clients. My thought is to set up a web service to allow the third party sites to access the files. The web service would be built in .Net using C#.

I am just wondering if there is a better way to do this? I can build a static web page to accomplish this I guess, but the files need to be a little secure and I figured that a web service would be easier to use for the third party developers than a static page.

Any help would be great.

Edit:
I need to add that the files to be downloaded are pdf files.

Comment: I would also recommend thinking about .ashx handlers, if you have an IIS server.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I found the following on it and it gives a great example http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/122/Simple-File-Download-Protection-with-ASP.NET

Comment: Only a little secure? :)

Comment: I should say we only want the files accessible from the third party sites. So maybe more secure than a little ;)